# Probabilistic time series returning results above thresholds (GluonTS)

Tags: python, tensorflow, mxnet, gluon, probability-distribution

I have a dataset with an upper numerical limit of 50, none of the samples go above this figure or below zero.

After running a deepAREstimator in GluonTS I get predictions way above 50 and also in the minuses. How can/could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to train the model slightly longer, and if possible on a larger dataset.
To prevent getting negative values just try a different distribution:
`distr_output=gluonts.distribution.NegativeBinomial`

But other than that its hard to tell without additional information what the problem is.